# The same dynamic page on different routes?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js. I have this page structure for orders:

```
/orders (pages/orders.vue)
/orders/123456 (pages/orders/_id.vue)
```

The `_id.vue` view is loaded as `<nuxt-child>` located in the orders.vue page. Can I have page setup (router setup) so that this page `pages/orders/_id.vue` is loaded in a different route, for example here:

```
/production (pages/production.vue)
/production/123456 (here I would like to load existing view pages/orders/_id.vue)
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [router-extras module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module)

```
<router>
    path: /posts
    alias:
        - /articles
        - /blog
</router>
```